# Javascript firing after two attempts

Tags: javascript, jquery, blazor

Ok maybe the title is worded a bit wrong...

I have some javascript that is supposed to open my sidebar once the button is clicked - But it is taking two clicks to open the sidebar and another two clicks to close..

I understand why this is happening via my Javascript - But not sure on the remedy (Not sure if its actually a Blazor issue?)

Javascript

```
function LoadContent() {

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",
        document.onclick = function(event) {

            const showNavbar = (toggleId, navId, pId, headerId) => {
                const toggle = document.getElementById(toggleId),
                    nav = document.getElementById(navId),
                    bodypd = document.getElementById(pId),
                    headerpd = document.getElementById(headerId);
                    mainbodypd = document.getElementById("mainbody");
                

                if (toggle && nav && bodypd && headerpd && mainbodypd) {
                    toggle.addEventListener("click",
                        () => {
                            nav.classList.toggle("show");
                            toggle.classList.toggle("bx-x");
                            bodypd.classList.toggle("body-pd");
                            headerpd.classList.toggle("body-pd");
                            mainbodypd.classList.toggle("height-100short");

                        });
                }
            };

            showNavbar("header-toggle", "nav-bar", "body-pd", "header");

            const linkColor = document.querySelectorAll(".nav_link");

            function colorLink() {
                if (linkColor) {
                    linkColor.forEach(l => l.classList.remove("active"));
                    this.classList.add("active");
                }
            }

            linkColor.forEach(l => l.addEventListener("click", colorLink));

        });
   
}
```

Can anyone explain, how i can prevent this from happening (Sorry, i am fairly new to JS)

Comment: You have click handlers being assigned inside of a click handler.  So it takes one click to even assign them.  Maybe you don't need the outer "document.onclick" handler at all.

Comment: small typo there `mainbodypd` is undefined

Comment: Isn't the whole idea of [tag:Blazor] that you don't use javascript?  "*Blazor lets you build interactive web UIs using C# **instead of** JavaScript.*"

Comment: As others have said: remove `document.onclick = function(event) {` so it runs on load not every time you click on the document

Comment: if i take that part away - i just keep getting exception - Could not find 'LoadContent' ('LoadContent' was undefined).

Comment: Error: Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: Could not find 'LoadContent' ('LoadContent' was undefined).
Error: Could not find 'LoadContent' ('LoadContent' was undefined).

Comment: if i leave it like this -    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",
       function(event) { i dont get any errors but it doesn't work at all

Comment: In looking at the actual content of your JavaScript, my question is this-- WHY are you trying to do any of this in JS at all?  Why aren't you changing your class names, colors, etc. just using C#?

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 not sure how to do it

Answer (score 0):

So why are you doing:

```
document.onclick = function(event) {
```

This makes the function trigger every page click ANYWHERE on the page (meaning you keep adding event listeners every time you click).

You should probably remove that part, or if you need it for something, take the shownavbar section out of it and just have it in DOMContentLoaded